# How to add a new column in a file

Tags: unit-testing, unix, awk, grep

I have file like this which contains 5 columns. But some rows in my file have 4 columns by mistake, for example in this file at the 5th and 6th rows, you can see that the second column is missing. I want to replace the missing 2nd column with a blank space without disturbing other rows in my file with field separator ",".

```
11111,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
22222,5323,6296,24-May-2010,1
33333,5323,6296,24-Jun-2010,1
44444,5323,6296,24-Jun-2010,1
55555,8061,15-Jul-2010,1
66666,6296,29-May-2010,1
77777,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
88888,6296,29-May-2010,1
99999,6296,27-May-2010,1
10101,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
```

Output that I need.

```
11111,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
22222,5323,6296,24-May-2010,1
33333,5323,6296,24-Jun-2010,1
44444,5323,6296,24-Jun-2010,1
55555,,8061,15-Jul-2010,1
66666,,6296,29-May-2010,1
77777,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
88888,,6296,29-May-2010,1
99999,,6296,27-May-2010,1
10101,5323,6296,29-May-2010,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
}

NF==5 { print; }
NF==4 { printf("%s,,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4); }
```

Answer (score 1):

shorter way

```
awk -F"," 'NF<5{sub(",",",,")}1' file
```

Comment: @Dennis: It is needed for the computation of `NF`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim I'd enter the following line in Ex-Mode:
:%s/^(\d+),(\d+,\d+-\w+-\d+,\d)$/\1, ,\2/g

Comment: Could be a good solution, provided all lines follow this format. But you have to specify \v (verymagic) to have magic operate (because parentheses and + should otherwise be escaped)